# CSS : Change input (type="text") so that the text start from the beginning of the input

Tags: html, css, input, less

I have the following simple `html` code:

```
<div class="contact-form-help-text">
   <input type="text" placeholder="How We Can Help You?" />
</div>
```

Here is its `LESS` code:

```
contact-form-help-text {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 440px;
  height: 140px;
  display: table;

  input {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    &::placeholder {
        color: #2ea8b0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

It gives me the following result where the placeholder is at the center of the `input` element:
[image]

And if I type in it, the text also starts from the center left of the element:
[image]

How to change my `Less/CSS` code so that the placeholder (and any text I write) is shown from the top left of the `input` element like this:

[image]

Comment: If you use table-cell display, reset vertical-align to top. You probably need here à textarea,  not an input. ;)

Comment: and add `text-align: left;` to the placeholder.

Comment: @tacoshy text align: left would only move the placeholder to the left side, I would like it to start from top left side

Comment: that wh @G-Cyrillus also said to use `vertical-align: top;`. However that will ojnly move the element to the top. So you need to use both. See my comment as completing the solution started by him.

Comment: I also suspect you are wanting a textarea not an input element as an input element will still confine the user to typing on one line - however long it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a textarea, not an input

```
<div class="contact-form-help-text">
   <textarea class="wideInput" placeholder="type text here"></textarea>
</div>


.wideInput{
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0.4em;
    padding-right: 0.4em;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply add `text-align: left; vertical-align: top;` to the placeholder css. `text-align: left;` will move the text to the left and `vertical-align: top;` to the top.

```
contact-form-help-text {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 440px;
  height: 140px;
  display: table;

  input {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    &::placeholder {
        color: #2ea8b0;
        opacity: 1;
        text-align: left;
    }
  }
}
```

Your issue is caused by `display: table-cell;` asn stated correctly by G-Cyrillus

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use textarea, here is the deal: https://codepen.io/julienduvart/pen/zYwLPmQ

```css
.contact-form-help-text {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 440px;
  height: 140px;
  display: table;
  // moving the border input in the parent
  border : 1px solid #000;

  input {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    // removing the border of the input
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    // apply a strict width (padding or border will not affect the width)
    box-sizing: border-box;

    &::placeholder {
        color: #2ea8b0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- change the div to label so you can focus on the input when clicking on the parent container --> 
<label class="contact-form-help-text">
   <input type="text" placeholder="How We Can Help You?" />
</label>
```

[image]

Comment: read the comments. There you clearly have all the solution aswell as the reason to this issue. Also do not use the answer option if you have questions to the OP. Use the comment option as soon as you have 50 or more reputation.

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation, so I can't comment ... sorry

Comment: yes but this does not allow you to mis-use the answer option to workaround to a given limitation.

Comment: Ok very, sorry, then I change my post to the solution without textarea.
So in fact I can't answer any of a question in stack overflow ?

Comment: no with your edit you now have a valid answer. You just can't use the answer option if you have no actual answer but just questions to ask to the OP (commentary answer)

Comment: Ok thank you for your information, I'm newbie 